# Xamarin iOS: FCM Notifications click event

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed FCM notifications in Xamarin.iOS app. Now I need navigation on notifications click, Where I can handle that to go to specific screen/viewController of app

My appDelegate Class with all overloaded methods

```
namespace edTheS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate,IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
    {        

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {

            LoginViewController loginCntl = new LoginViewController();

                var loginCntl1 = new LoginViewController();
                this.navCntl = new UINavigationController(loginCntl1);
                this.navCntl.NavigationBarHidden = true;
                Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
             InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh(TokenRefreshNotification);

            //Register your app for remote notifications.
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                //For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
            //For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;

            }   
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            App.Configure();
            return true;
        }

      public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
     {
          // Invoked when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.
            // This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) 
            // or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Games should use this method to pause the game.
     }

     public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
        {
          // Called as part of the transiton from background to active state.
           // Here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
      }

     public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)
      {
          // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data, if needed. See also DidEnterBackground.
       }


        // You'll need this method if you set "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled": NO in GoogleService-Info.plist
        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            SISConst.PushInfo = new PushNotification();
            SISConst.PushInfo.DeviceID = deviceToken.ToString();
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(deviceToken.ToString(),"dToken"); 
            InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken (deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);

            //InstanceId.SharedInstance.a


            #if DEBUG
            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);
#endif
#if RELEASE
            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Prod);
#endif

        }


     //public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
      //{
      //    Console.WriteLine("Failed to register for remote notifications {0}", error.LocalizedDescription);
      //}


      //FCM-- This method calling when notifications delivering
      public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
       {

            Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

            // Generate custom event
            NSString[] keys = { new NSString("Event_type") };
            NSObject[] values = { new NSString("Recieve_Notification") };
            var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);
            //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            string studentId = string.Empty, OrgNameSubTtl = string.Empty, moduleTitle = string.Empty, bodyText = string.Empty;
            // Send custom event
            Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent("CustomEvent", parameters);

            if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
            {

                //var title = notification.Request.Content.Title;      
                var remotePushData = userInfo.ToDictionary(i => i.Key.ToString(), i => i.Value.ToString());

                ScheduleNotification(moduleTitle.ToString(),OrgNameSubTtl.ToString(),bodyText.ToString());
            }

            else if(application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Background)
            {

                var remotePushData = userInfo.ToDictionary(i => i.Key.ToString(), i => i.Value.ToString());

                ScheduleNotification(moduleTitle.ToString(), OrgNameSubTtl.ToString(), bodyText.ToString());
            }
            else if(application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive)
            {

                var remotePushData = userInfo.ToDictionary(i => i.Key.ToString(), i => i.Value.ToString());

                ScheduleNotification(moduleTitle.ToString(), OrgNameSubTtl.ToString(), bodyText.ToString());
            }

        }


        //FCM
        // To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 10 devices.
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            string studentId = string.Empty, OrgNameSubTtl = string.Empty,moduleTitle=string.Empty,bodyText=string.Empty; 
            //var title = notification.Request.Content.Title;      
            var remotePushData = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo.ToDictionary(i => i.Key.ToString(), i => i.Value.ToString());

            ScheduleNotification(moduleTitle,OrgNameSubTtl,bodyText);
        }

 //Workaround for handling notifications in background for iOS 10
        [Export ("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]

        public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Notifications clicked......");
        }

       public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
       {
            //FCM
            Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from FCM");
        }

        void ScheduleNotification(string title,string OrgSubtitle,string body)
        {
            //Create content
            var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
            content.Title = title;
            content.Subtitle = OrgSubtitle;
            content.Body = body;
            content.Badge = 0;
            content.CategoryIdentifier = "categoryID";
            content.Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default;


            // Fire trigger in one seconds
            var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(1, false);

            var requestID = "customNotification";
            var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

            // This is the line that does the trick
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new CustomUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate();

            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) => {
                if (err != null)
                {
                    // Report error
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", err);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Report Success
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Notification Scheduled: {0}", request);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

From the above code none of method calling on notification click.
Please suggest me better way

CustomUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate is separate class

```
public class CustomUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        string studentId = string.Empty, OrgNameSubTtl = string.Empty,moduleNmae=string.Empty,bodyText=string.Empty; 

        public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
        {
            // Here you handle the user taps
            completionHandler();

            var remotePushData = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo.ToDictionary(i => i.Key.ToString(), i => i.Value.ToString());

        }
        public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge);

        }
```

Comment: When you tap the notification the event `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()` will trigger. If you want to use actions, `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()` will trigger. Which problem are you facing?

Comment: @LandL `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()`  triggering for me when notification deliver(as I am showing comment in my code) and `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()` not calling at all.

Comment: Try to add `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;` when you register remote notification.

Comment: I am doing this. Please see my code below this line. My all code like this only
`if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))`

Comment: Then also can't trigger `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()`?

Comment: `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()` never triggering. `WillPresentNotification()`  (in second part of code) trigger very few cases on _notifications click_

Comment: I notice that is it your editing format or your code is right there. Please change a new line when you write `[Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]`.

Comment: This is my actual code i am using.

Comment: Export attribute can't be written with region, please separate them to two lines.

Comment: Now i have break line after setting attribute(In edited code) then also not working.
if you see here in link how they are importing attributes.
[See here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Firebase.CloudMessaging/samples/CloudMessagingSample/CloudMessagingSample/AppDelegate.cs)